# Showing oracle database values into gridview

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g, sql-plus-dot-net

Hi i've an oracle database with the table PROVA with 3 columns NOME, COGNOME, NUMTELEFONO.
i'm searching to update my gridview in c# with the value in contained into the table.
This is my code and into the method button1_Click() i need to show db values into my gridview c# app. Can someone help me with the code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess;



namespace dbOracleForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connectionString = "Data Source =  (DESCRIPTION = "+
    "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))" +
    "(CONNECT_DATA = " +
     " (SERVER = DEDICATED) " + 
     " (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.home) " +
    ")"+
  "); User Id = system;password = orcl;";
            OracleConnection  con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            con.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOME, COGNOME, NUMTELEFONO FROM PROVA ORDER BY COGNOME DESC";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataGridView1.DataSource(dt);



        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Oracle .NET Developer Center](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet.html) , [Introducing Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/intro.html) , and [Using ODP.NET Client Provider in a Simple Application](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/intro005.html)

Comment: Here's another post that may be useful: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/OracleDataAdapterClass.htm#i1001593

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ...

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NOME, COGNOME, NUMTELEFONO FROM PROVA ORDER BY COGNOME DESC";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        dataGridView1.DataSource(dt);//wrong
        dataGridView1.DataSource= dt;//correct



    }
```